# Decompiling classes.dex file doesn't show my actual java code

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, decompiling, dex2jar

I developed an app using the android studio and tested it on my phone. Then, I formatted my laptop and my code was gone. Now, I want my code back. So, I got 
 the apk of my app by using shareit app which shares the apk. I decompiled it using these steps -

- Converted .apk to .zip
- Extracted that zip file to get .dex file
- There I get various dex files like classes.dex, classes2.dex etc
- Converted them to jar using dex2jar
- Opened the jar file using JD-Gui application

But still, it doesn't show my actual java code. Is there a way I can get it back. I don't want to write the code again.

[Screenshot of decompiled .dex file -> jar file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mxfJ.png)

Comment: Nope. That's the best you can get.

Comment: So, I have to rewrite the whole code again..

Comment: Nope, you can use the code you get from decompiling as base.

Comment: But, that code isn't related to what I originally wrote in any way.

Comment: "Then, I formatted my laptop and my code was gone" -- check the source code out of your version control system. Or, restore it from a backup that you made of your computer.

Comment: I'm not having any backup for this code neither it is on VCS, just left with this apk that I tested on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

1-extract your classes.jar files and open .class file with JD-Gui or DJ JAVA Decompiler.

2-try using DJ JAVA Decompiler

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u0k5.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rog1.png

Comment: Yes, I can open these files like that but still, this is not the actual code I wrote or it isn't similar to that in any way.

Comment: thats so strange!

Comment: exactly!! if it is ok with u then u can try I can share my apk with u.

Comment: Please give me ur email id so that I can send u my apk.

Comment: toomaris@gmail.com

Comment: Please check ur mail

Comment: Did you get this resolved.. i am having the same issue